# Error with No Escape Character in Mapping Data Flow in Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

TLDR: Why does Azure Data Factory Data Flow not allow you to have no escape character?

We have bad source data from a source that is unlikely to update it on their end (this is the nicest way I could phrase this). They have multiple columns where the value in the column is 01F\ or 8239\ and the backslash is written in their spec to be part of the value, not to be considered an escape character like it is standardized to be in the entire world.

The overall set up of the files are that they are comma delimited, each column's contents is in " ", and we have all of the normal new line characters. It's just the backslash that is not complying with standards. E.g.

```
"Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4"
"John","01F\","34","NY"
"Jane","3K","8239\","CA"

|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Column 1       |     Column 2     |     Column 3     |     Column 4     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        "John"       |       "01F\"     |       "34"       |         "NY"     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        "Jane"       |        "3K"      |      "8239\"     |         "CA"     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

In Azure Data Factory we are trying to see if we can make it ignore the \ as being an escape character. (FYI when we leave it as being treated as an escape character, it pulls the column right after the column with the backslash into one column). We can see in the data set where to set it so that there is no escape character.

[image]

However when we then add that data set to our data flow and attempt to preview the data there, we get an error that we can't have no escape character in the data flow, and that quote character should be no quote character when we have no escape character.

[image]

If we try to go back and also set no quote characters (which we don't actually want to do, just to test if that'll let it work), we get an error that the data flow can't have no escape or quote characters.

[image]

What is the purpose of having those two options available if they do not work in Azure Data Factory? Or is there somewhere else we need to update additional settings to make this work?


Thank you!!


Edit: I forgot to mention that we also attempted to see if we could replace the backslashes in the data flow column mapping section. We tried using the replace() function, but could not get it to work (kept giving syntax errors).

```
ORIGINAL working code for column: trim(toString($$))
ATTEMPTED WORKAROUNDS:
replace(trim(toString($$)),'\','-')
trim(replace(toString($$),'\','-')
trim(toString(replace($$),'\','-'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to share that a user on the Microsoft forums provided an answer that ended up working.

We changed the escape character from \ to ^ in the data set settings (only did this after confirming that the ^ character is not used in any fashion anywhere). We did not apply the replace function in the mapping of the column because unfortunately we needed to keep the \ character in those columns. But it worked and our data is now flowing through the way we need it to (even though these are not best practices for data management).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/48595/error-with-no-escape-character-in-mapping-data-flo.html

Answer (score 0):

For the 'Delimited Text' source, it does not allow you to select Quote character with 'No escape character'. You can try the workaround options

1. If your destination is Azure Synapse, try with Polybase load. (It will load the data with escape sequence and Quote character. After data load you can do a cleansing.)
2. If possible convert the source data format from 'Delimited Text' to 'parquet' or 'Json'

Comment: We are not loading into Azure Synapse, just into our Delta Lake so we can access through Databricks. To convert the source data format to parquet from the original CSV, we would need to create a copy activity correct?